# numpy dataframe get maximum difference in a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the biggest temperature change in a dataframe of countries.

My first idea was to make groups: `df.groupby('country_code')['temperature'].max()`, `df.groupby('country_code')['temperature'].min()`, subtract them, and get the maximum.

I guess there is a better way to to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like passing a custom `max-min` function to [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) is fastest. The alternatives are slower:

- using [`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) inside `agg`;
- using `apply` (see [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76672799/18470692) by [@MariaKozlova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22052558/maria-kozlova))

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility

# sample df: 10 countries with 5 temperatures
data = {'country_code': np.repeat(range(10),5), 'temperature': np.random.randint(-10,50,50)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# method1 (pass lambda function to `agg`)
out = df.groupby('country_code', sort=False)['temperature'].agg(lambda x: max(x) - min(x))

# method2 (pass `np.ptp` to `agg`)
out2 = df.groupby('country_code', sort=False).agg({'temperature': np.ptp})

out.equals(out2['temperature'])
# True

out

country_code
0    53
1    56
2    44
3    57
4    23
5    29
6    42
7    47
8    27
9    25
Name: temperature, dtype: int64
```

**Performance comparison**

```
# intriguingly, `np.ptp` is actually quite a bit slower
%timeit df.groupby('country_code', sort=False)['temperature'].agg(lambda x: max(x) - min(x))
# 238 µs ± 4.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby('country_code', sort=False).agg({'temperature': np.ptp})
# 1.26 ms ± 22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# adding comparison for `apply` (solution by @MariaKolzova)
def temp_range(group):
    return group.max() - group.min()

%timeit df.groupby('country_code')['temperature'].apply(temp_range)
# 434 µs ± 9.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: If you time it on larger DataFrames, an even faster way is `g = df.groupby('country_code', sort=False) ; g.max()-g.min()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach, dealing with only one set of groups

```
def temp_range(group):
    return group.max() - group.min()

df.groupby('country_code')['temperature'].apply(temp_range)
```

Not sure if it's better though